# Launching LeanModal from within a function

Tags: jquery

I've correctly implemented leanModal so that it launches from a button with the following code:

```
$("#modal_trigger").leanModal({
    top: 200,
    overlay: 0.6,
    closeButton: ".modal_close"
});
```

However elsewhere I need to call it from within a jquery function but I can't seem to get it to work. Basically the logic is 'if cookie does not exist launch leanModal, else launch item you wanted'. I've been struggling with it for a while, I would have thought you can launch it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Launch banking pop up
$('.game, .gameBig').click(function (ev) {
    if ($.cookie('fCookie') == undefined) {
        leanModal();
    } else {
        window.open('images/game.png', 'Continue_to_Application', 'width=695,height=500');
    }
    ev.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
</script>
```

I had some limited success replacing `leanModal()` with:

```
$('.game, .gameBig').leanModal({
    top: 200,
    overlay: 0.6,
    closeButton: ".modal_close"
});
```

but I know I'm going wrong somewhere. Any help you can give greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you sure that the condition is correct? can you try to move the ev.preventDefault(); on top and remove the return false.

Comment: Thanks Bruno but it didn't seem to make a difference. I know the cookie check works as I had an alert there before.

Comment: the problem then could be the selector, on the first you use a unique selector and only 1, on your second example you use classes and two items. just as a test can you add an id to the element and remove the selector and use the id one?

Comment: I just tried it but it didn't work. Thanks for trying Bruno, I'll struggle on and post an answer if I find it. I managed to get the overlay to appear but without the login box on top. Not much good :)